# What does the ["string"] notation mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am using the Mongoose Encryption package, and I came across the notation where the value of the key is in the form of ["string"]. In the following code, age is the key of a key-value pair for a mongoose schema object, and the code wraps the variable age within quotation marks and square brackets. Doing some research, I came upon Computed Property Names from ES6, so does this mean that the value of encryptedFields is all the keys named age? Also, is this the only way to target the age key or is there some other notation?

```
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { encryptionKey: encKey, signingKey: sigKey, encryptedFields: ['age'] });
```

Comment: In your JS code, it's just basic array notation. It's an array with a single item, which is the string `'age'`. I suppose from mongoose's perspective it's a list of field names found on the schema object. Computed property names in JS is when the square brackets are used where the property name is defined, i.e. on the left side of the colon.

Comment: `"does this mean that the value of encryptedFields is all the keys named age?"` I'm pretty sure that `age` is the field *(database column)* you want to encrypt... I've never used mongoose myself, though.